# external link sends me internally

Tags: php, html

I am have a form that requests a user to submit a website and then on a different page I send a mysql query to retrieve that website an and turn it into a link by doing this in PHP (V=5.6)

```
$link = '<a href=' . $school_website .' target="_blank">' . $school_website . '</a>';
```

the problem is that when i try to click this link, instead of sending me to www.google.com for example, it directs me to www.mydomain.com/www.google.com.

I fixed it originally by using substr to see if the first part was "www" and if it was adding "http://" to it and it worked but now i realize that not all websites will start out with that.

I have tried googling this problem but Im not quite sure how to word the problem so I am not getting anything.

My apologies if this is a duplicate. I did not see anything here that fits my problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you post you php code for eg : $school_website variable value

Comment: Absolute URLs start with `http://` and everything else is relative to the current domain.

Comment: It's up to you to normalize data from mysql so that all links begin with http:// or https://.

Comment: $school_website = $school['website'];

Comment: I have other calls for other information and they work ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could always check if it has http/s:// with regex, if it hasn't then add http:// and the link will work as it should. Or make it ugly but simple.

Simplest way is to remove any protocol and prepend // - that would mark the link as absolute and adopt your current protocol. Even if it didn't have http/s:// it would work as it should.

```
$school_website = '//' . str_ireplace(['https://', 'http://'], '', $school_website);
```

Example: 
`https://google.com` becomes `//google.com`
`google.com` becomes `//google.com`
`www.google.com` becomes `//www.google.com`

In any of the above cases it would become a absolute url.

A better but longer way would be to validate the url with regex.

Comment: that works perfectly. Thank you. My google fu was really failing me

Answer (score 0):

You need `http://` or `https://` at the beginning of the URL of external links - in fact that should be part of your variable "$school_website", and if that one is for example retrieved from a database, that value has to be changed in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Until you add `http://` or `https://`in front of url. It will remain the relative

Like if you re on `www.mydomain.com` and your `href` attribute value is `www.google.com`, The attribute  value remain the relative and will target to
you url.